# Listing all org mode todo items in agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am new to emacs and org mode. I have created a .org file and put in a set of TODO tasks. I have defined the following TODO states in the file

```
#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(t@/!) | STARTED(p@/!) | ONGOING(o@/!) | DONE(d@/!) | CANCELLED (x@/!) | DEFERRED(f@/!) | WAITING(w@/!)
```

When I create the agenda view (by pressing C-c a a), it only shows the items in the TODO state. But I want it to display tasks in all TODO states.

I've searched for this on google, and have gone through the documentation for org mode, but could not figure out how to do this.

Can someone tell me how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The agenda lists all active tasks (vs completed ones).

Your problem above is you're putting multiple "pipe" symbols; you must just have ONE, to separate incomplete keywords from completed ones.